# How to parse the Json data in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am new to windows phone 8 development. I am working on application in which I need parse the Json. so I am not able to get the following data in windows phone 8.

```
 {
   "response":{
      "errorFlag":0,
      "Score Detail":{
         "39":[
            {
               "test_date":"2013-06-28",
               "total_marks":"50",
               "score":"14"
            },
            {
               "test_date":"2013-08-08",
               "total_marks":"20",
               "score":"20"
            }
         ],
         "40":[
            {
               "test_date":"2013-08-08",
               "total_marks":"20",
               "score":"20"
            },
            {
               "test_date":"2013-08-08",
               "total_marks":"30",
               "score":"20"
            },
            {
               "test_date":"2013-08-08",
               "total_marks":"30",
               "score":"20"
            }
         ],
         "50":[
            {
               "test_date":"2013-08-08",
               "total_marks":"30",
               "score":"20"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

I am trying to parse the data in the following way

```
namespace testscore
{
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Mainpage_Loaded);
    }
 void Mainpage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient webClient1 = new WebClient();
        webClient1.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient1_DownloadStringCompleted);
        webClient1.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("some link"));
    }

public void webClient1_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result);
        MessageBox.Show(e.Result.ToString());
        foreach (var res in rootObject.response.ScoreDetail)
        {
            string rs = res.Key;
            MessageBox.Show(rs.ToString());

            ......
        }                                          
    }

public class RootObject
    {
        public Response response { get; set; }
    }

    public class Response
    {
        public int errorFlag { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Score Detail")]
        public JObject ScoreDetail { get; set; }           
    }
```

Here I am to getting key value (here it is 39) but I am not able to get the values of the score, testdate and marks. please help me in parsing these details.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The '39' property name can change ?

Comment: No, Here I need get the data for the perticular(39) number only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I propose you to build classes of your json :

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Response response { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public int errorFlag { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Score Detail")]
    public JObject ScoreDetail { get; set; }
}
```

You can use them on the DownloadStringCompleted event :

```
public void webClient1_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    RootObject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result);
    JObject obj = root.response.ScoreDetail;
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> pair in obj)
    {   
        string key = pair.Key; // here you got 39.
        foreach (JObject detail in pair.Value as JArray)
        {
            string date = detail["test_date"].ToString();
            string score = detail["score"].ToString();
            string total_marks = detail["total_marks"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: It is correct but u have hard coded "39" and its an array so it will have multiple values. It can be "40" or "50" too. It is dynamic.How to do that?

Comment: That's why I asked you if you have something else that "39" property... I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result= JObject.Parse(response)["response"]["ScoreDetail"];
                                    foreach (var item in result)
                                    {

// Code to store the result
}
```