# Receive data from API (or through WebSocket)

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to receive data from some remote server which send JSON response.

What I want to get is to send a request from mobile app, parse this JSON and display it to user. Could anyone tell me how to do it? How to start?

*I was also wondering to use WebSocket. Is it possible to change data in application through server request? If it is then how to do it?

What I get by now:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://...");
request.BeginGetResponse(Callback, request);
```

Don't know what to do in callback function - how to get JSON response and parse it :/

Comment: Tell more brief, What exactly application is?

Comment: I want to get news from my own server

Answer (score 0):

First install [HTTP Client library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http) using Nuget.

Now request the data from your server using the code

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("http:/myserver/api/values"); 
var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

This will store your JSON string in the `responseString` variable which you can parse to get the data you need./

For details on how to parse JSON see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120092/how-to-parse-the-json-data-in-windows-phone-8)