# Read json file and store it in string UWP C#

Tags: c#, json

Whenever I run my application I get the following exception

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.IO.FileSystem.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Synchronous operations should not be performed on the UI thread.  Consider wrapping this method in Task.Run.

```
string json = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\PC\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ApiInUniversal\ApiInUniversal\Assets\stream.json");
```

How can I parse JSON?

Comment: Did you consider wrapping the method in `Task.Run`? ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
public async void ProcessRead()
{
 string filePath = @"temp2.txt";

 if (File.Exists(filePath) == false)
 {
     Debug.WriteLine("file not found: " + filePath);
 }
 else
 {
     try
     {
         string text = await ReadTextAsync(filePath);
         Debug.WriteLine(text);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
     }
 }
}
```

you can look at parsing the json [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120092/how-to-parse-the-json-data-in-windows-phone-8) , [here 2](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Json-Parsing-in-windows-74d89955)